# Difficult XPath with more conditions

Tags: xml, xpath, multiple-conditions

```
 <devices>
    <deviceType>PHONE</deviceType>
    <account>717</accountId>
    <attributes>
      <value>New PHONE 1</value>
      <key>FRIENDLY_NAME</key>
    </attributes>
    <attributes>
      <value>TRUE</value>
      <key>DOWNLOAD </key>
    </attributes>
    <attributes>
      <value>1454737</value>
      <key> TIMESTAMP</key>
    </attributes>
    <deviceId>550BDC49DA724C</deviceId>
  </devices>
  <devices>
    <deviceType>WEB</deviceType>
    <accountId>717</accountId>
    <attributes>
      <value>2016-04-11 08:53:52.866;</value>
      <key>REGISTRATION </key>
    </attributes>
    <attributes>
      <value>TRUE</value>
      <key>ACTIVE_DEVICE</key>
    </attributes>
    <creationDate>146036872</creationDate>
    <deviceId>997C6AADB51</deviceId>
  </devices>
```

I need to get the value of deviceId WHERE deviceType=PHONE, TABLET or WEB and this device has attributes with key=DOWNLOAD and value=TRUE. Thanks for the right XPath.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I need to get the value of deviceId WHERE deviceType=PHONE, TABLET or WEB and this device has attributes with key=DOWNLOAD and value=TRUE"*

This is one possible way :

```
//devices[deviceType='PHONE' or deviceType='TABLET' or deviceType='WEB']
         [attributes[key='DOWNLOAD' and value='TRUE']]
 /deviceId
```

Demo: [`xpathtester`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/5c98eb7a08547566b157346c8de44959), [`xpatheval`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/Ct3_2o3fb)

Comment: To OP: use `normalize-space(key)` if the value of `key` in your actual XML may contains extra whitespace

Comment: @Michal what do you mean by *another way*? What kind of way you need?